# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Каждый город этой страны известен чем-то уникальным, поэтому, выбрав поездку в Грецию, туристы узнают про древнюю историю государства, национальную кухню, а также посетят торжественные праздники, характеризующие греческий народ.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый город этой страны известен чем-то уникальным, поэтому, выбрав поездку в Грецию, туристы узнают про древнюю историю государства, **ознакомятся с национальной кухней, а также народными праздниками и обычаями**.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Куда народ делся?

Comment: Праздники, характеризующие греческий народ,  стали народными праздниками (греческого народа).

Answer (score 1):

Не нахожу логической связи между первой и второй частью. Почему второе следует из первого? Туристы узнают про древнюю историю, национальную кухню, посетят праздники — потому что каждый город известен чем-то уникальным?! А если города не были бы уникальными — туристам не рассказали бы о древней истории и национальной кухне?

"Узнают про древнюю историю государства" — звучит не очень хорошо, как будто туристы не знали о существовании древней истории.

"Торжественные праздники, характеризующие греческий народ" — тоже не очень хорошо. Праздники — они скорее веселые, чем торжественные. Не уверен, что праздники характеризуют народ (может и характеризуют, но только с одной стороны).

Мой вариант:

**Каждый город этой страны известен чем-то уникальным. Выбрав поездку в Грецию, туристы познакомятся с древней историей государства, национальной кухней, а также народными праздниками и обычаями.**